# Erlang maximum erlang concurrent httpc:request connections

Tags: erlang

i get url content by httpc:request

i run a 100 000 spawn process of httpc: httpc:request,

but the maximum speed with which data always is getting 0.5MB per second

my internet channel 1000MB per second

what settings i need to do to make httpc:request 1000MB per second?

some elements on my code

```
ok = ensure_start(ssl),
ok = ensure_start(inets),
ok = httpc:set_options([{max_sessions, 2000000}, {pipeline_timeout, 20000}     ], default),
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what your internet bandwidth is if the server at the other end is low on resources (like bandwidth, CPU, memory etc)

Comment: if i run multiple 10x virtual machines  eralng copy the velocity increased, my speed does not depend on external machines. as I can run 100,000 processes at 100% load and the channel, but the channel actually loaded on 0,5 mb / s - it's problem erlang virutal machine?